# What is the easiest way to reset migrations in Heroku CLI?

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-cli

I recently deployed Django REST API project on Heroku and I wanted to remove migrations and migrate again.

I have tried:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate --app cyberminds-backend zero
```

but it returns:

```
CommandError: No installed app with label 'zero'
```

What are the easiest steps or commands to achieve this?

Comment: Was zero intended as part of the command to run? If so, why is it positioned there?

Comment: @jonrsharpe as its mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793985/18330318 `zero` is a command

Comment: I see, but you're putting it after the _Heroku_ app name, hence the error you're getting, not as part of the command for Heroku to run.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where should it be placed? before app name? Honestly I can't figure this out

Comment: Try `heroku run --help` to see the syntax and options. Note `--app` is an argument _to the Heroku CLI_, and **not** part of the command you want it to run in the dyno. The app name mentioned in the linked question is separate, it's not the _Heroku_ app name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: @TeshAych, the `appname` mentioned in that other answer (which I wrote) refers to the [_Django_ application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/). Do you remember running [`python manage.py startapp something`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/django-admin/#startapp)? It's that `something`, whatever you called your Django app. We're migrating the migrations _for one Django app_ back to zero, so you'll want something like `heroku run python manage.py migrate something zero --app cyberminds-backend`.

Comment: Depending on how your local project directory is set up, the `--app cyberminds-backend` part might not be necessary. See [How does `heroku config` know what app to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201290/354577) and [How to avoid the --app option with heroku CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577)

Comment: @Chris now it works. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.